# C++ type conversion precedence in a return

Tags: c++, types, stl, casting, type-conversion

I have a code that is being changed to compile in a 64-bit mode where previously it was being compiled in Win32 for various reasons.  This has caused some cleanup work to address some warnings, so I'm picking through code and found something that looks like this:

```
class foo 
{

public:
    int foo() { return data_.size()-1; }

private:
    std::vector<int> data_;
};
```

The size() method on STL containers returns unsigned values.  The return value is being cast into a signed integer value so there's a conversion that will occur at some point.

I'm not sure about the precedence here though.  Will the value that *size()* is returning get cast to an int and then have 1 subtracted, which would result in the return value being -1 if size was zero?  Or will we subtract 1 from an unsigned int, possibly doing bad things if the container is empty when this gets called?

Thanks!

Comment: It will be unsigned = unsigned - 1; return signed(unsigned) where unsigned(0) - 1 == unsigned(max)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be unsigned = unsigned - 1; return signed(unsigned) where unsigned(0) - 1 == unsigned(max)

From 4.7 Integral conversions

> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another
>   integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be
>   converted to a prvalue of an integer type. If the destination type is
>   unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent
>   to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to
>   represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement
>   representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change
>   in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). — end note ] **If the
>   destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be
>   represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise,
>   the value is implementation-defined.**

Hence any unsigned value greater than the maximum signed value leads to implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If the size is 0 the result is not -1 but a very large integer "18446744073709551615" (unsigned(max)).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<int> nums {};

    std::cout << "nums contains " << nums.size()-1 << " elements.\n";
    // nums contains 18446744073709551615 elements.
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a69d4af99ba77f47

Comment: This link has casting to int.

Comment: Look at my link. I added a conversion to `int` (as OP has) and got `-1`

Comment: Yes it is correct. You added type casting to int from unsigned int. The original code has `return data_.size()-1;` without casting. So in the case of calling data_.size() in an empty vector you will get a larger number (unsigned(max)).

Comment: in your example in both versions you get max int value. In the 32 bit version you get 2^32 -1  = 4294967295 and in the 64 bit version you get 2^64 - 1 = 18446744073709551615

Answer (score 0):

Your second guess is correct. In general, evaluating any expression of the form

```
exp1 op exp2
```

works in the steps

1. evaluate `exp1`
2. evaluate `exp2`
3. apply `op` on the values of `exp1` and `exp2`

**Note**: steps 1 and 2 can occur in any sequence. The point is *each operand is evaluated before applying the operator*.

So in this case `exp1` will evaluated as an `unsigned int` value first, and may have undesirable effect.

Comment: Exp2 can be evaluated first.

Answer (score 0):

When `data_.size()-1` is evaluated as an unsigned integer. When `data_.size()` is `0`, the function could return a very large positive number instead of `-1`.

Your best option:

```
int foo() { int s = data_.size(); return s-1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The next program returns `i=-1`. The bit pattern of `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` is that one of the `int` `-1`. This is the reason why your code works in w32.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  std::cout << "i=" << static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()) << '\n';
}

/*
  Local Variables:
  compile-command: "g++ test.cc -o a.exe && ./a.exe"
  End:
*/
```

But, you rely in your code on the translation of signed integral types and unsigned ones. The types must fit! Therefore, better use `std::ptrdiff_t` and `std::size_t`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  std::cout << "i=" << static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()) << '\n';
}

/*
  Local Variables:
  compile-command: "g++ test.cc -o a.exe && ./a.exe"
  End:
*/
```